# How do you install `npm` on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

According to this page:

https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

it says:

> To publish and install packages to and from the public npm registry or
> your company's npm Enterprise registry, you must install Node.js and
> the npm command line interface using either a Node version manager or
> a Node installer.

Then gives `npm install -g npm` which won't work cos `npm` isn't installed.

`nvm` doesn't work:

```
nvm install npm   
Version 'npm' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
```

Clicking on the `nvm` link takes you to the `nvm` GitHub page.

Half way down I found this:
`nvm install-latest-npm`
which fails with:

```
nvm install-latest-npm 
Attempting to upgrade to the latest working version of npm...
Unable to obtain npm version.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this article will meet your needs : [node.js](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18.04/)

Comment: try `sudo apt install nodejs`

Comment: There are different ways you can install it, for example [using Ubuntu's package manager](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) but I find [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) (Node Version Manager) most convenient (because it allows me to easily switch versions). You should get `npm` automatically if you install Node with nvm. If you don't, then you'll have to investigate why it's not doing what it should do.

Answer (score 1):

nvm is for installing node not npm, npm will be installed

What you're doing with `nvm install npm`, is attempting to install a node version called npm.

Do `nvm install 14`, let it run, check for errors, then once installed your have npm.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
```

Answer (score -1):

Just run these scripts and you are good to go.

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install nodejs
```

It installs nodejs as well as npm.